# why is this complexType definition correct

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

As I always thought, `xs:restriction` is used to restrict a certain simpleType or complexType, hence the name `restriction`. But the xsd snippet below is correct. Take a look at the `Norwegian_customer`, the `country` is overwritten with complexType, so it's extended, not restricted. And it's renamed. What exactly does `xs:restriction` want to offer? Is `xs:restriction` the superset of `xs:extension`? The snippet is validated in `WebStorm`.

```
  <xs:complexType name="customer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Norwegian_customer">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="customer">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="country1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2):

> But the xsd snippet below is correct.

**No, your XSD snippet is not correct**.  `Norwegian_customer` is not a valid restriction of `customer` because it does not allow `country`, only `country1`.  All of the parts of the content model of the restricted base type must be explicitly allowed in the derived type.

> The snippet is validated in WebStorm.

**If Webstorm validated this XSD, then it is non-conformant.**

See [W3C XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/), specifically:

- [Schema Component Constraint: Particle Derivation OK
  (All:All,Sequence:Sequence -- Recurse) #2](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#rcase-Recurse)
- [Schema Component Constraint: Derivation Valid (Restriction, Complex) #5.4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#derivation-ok-restriction)

**Note that Xerces-based validators would have informed you as follows:**

> [Error] try.xsd:13:45: rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete
>   functional mapping between the particles.
>
> [Error] try.xsd:13:45: derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type
>   'Norwegian_customer'.  The particle of the type is not a valid
>   restriction of the particle of the base.